# data.table subset condition on .SD columns?

Tags: r, data.table

I want to create the same result as the below minimum reproducible example, but you can see the subsetting condition on the last code is basically remove rows where .SD columns should not be **all zero**.

```
library(dplyr)

library(data.table)

set.seed(1)

t1 <- sample(-1:1, 999999, replace = T) %>% matrix(ncol = 9) %>% as.data.table %>% {cbind.data.frame(id = 1:nrow(.), .)}

t1[V1 != 0|V2 != 0|V3 != 0|V4 != 0|V5 != 0|V6 != 0|V7 != 0|V8 != 0|V9 != 0, lapply(.SD, sum), by = id]
```

I have tried

```
t1[sum(abs(.SD)) != 0, lapply(.SD, sum), by = id]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `rowSums()`:

```
t1[t1[, rowSums(.SD != 0) > 0, .SD = patterns("V\\d")]
   ][, lapply(.SD, sum), by = id]
```

Answer (score 2):

We can create the `i` with `Reduce`

```
i1 <- t1[, .I[Reduce(`|`, lapply(.SD, `!=`, 0))], .SDcols = V1: V9]
out2 <- t1[i1, lapply(.SD, sum), by = id]
```

-checking with OP's output

```
out1 <- t1[V1 != 0|V2 != 0|V3 != 0|V4 != 0|V5 != 0|V6 != 0|V7 != 0|V8 != 0|V9 != 0, lapply(.SD, sum), by = id]  
identical(out1, out2)
#[1] TRUE
```